# Signification de « que c'est »

Tags: pronoms-relatifs, exclamations

> Le bon garçon que c'est !

Je ne comprends pas la structure de cette phrase. Est-ce une tournure exclamative ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Le point d'exclamation ne laisse guère de doute sur la nature exclamative de cette tournure...

Voici comment on peut la réécrire :

> Que c'est un bon garçon !
>
> Qu'est que c'est un bon garçon !
>
> Le bon garçon qu'il est !

Comment: Merci. Peut-on employer aussi : **Bon qu'il est ce garçon !** et  **Comme ce garçon est bon !** ?

Comment: On a bien une petite liberté dans l'ordre des mots d'une phrase mais on sort ici du cadre de ce qui est généralement admis (le français n'est pas le latin !), encore que la phrase reste très compréhensible et puisse être utilisée dans une tournure humoristique.